# How to do raw query in Bookshelf.js

Tags: bookshelf.js, knex.js

I want to achieve this

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

from https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?hl=fr#createtable

How can I make this query with Bookshelf.

I have this now:

```
var raw = '( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( '+ req.params.lat + ' ) ) * cos( radians( '+req.params.lng+' ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( '+req.body.lng+' ) ) ) ) AS distance';


new Places().query(function(qb) {
    qb.where('lat',req.params.lat); 
    qb.where('lng',req.params.lng); 
    qb.column(raw);
    qb.having('distance', '>', 25);
}).fetch({ debug: false }).then(function(collection) {
    console.log(collection);

    if (collection === undefined) {
        // no such result
        res.json(404,{error: "No Places found."});
    } else {
        // found, list json
        res.json(200, collection);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its.

```
qb.column(qb.knex.raw(raw));
```

Answer (score 9):

I found this to work .. no *qb.* instance/reference required:

```
var Bookshelf = require('bookshelf').mysqlAuth;

var rawSql = 'SELECT .. <etc>';

Bookshelf.knex.raw(rawSql).then(..);
```

Answer (score 1):

i Tried something like this which worked fine

```
return **Location**.query(qb => {
      return ***query***
    })
    .fetchAll()
    .then(data => data.toJSON());
```

With:

- **Location** is a Model (I am doing it inside strapi services)
- ***query*** can be any raw query.