# Bookshelf js collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I'm trying to use bookshelf collections and return a entire table

```
< TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
<     at CollectionBase (/projects/twitter/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/base/collection.js:30:18)
<     at child [as constructor] (/projects/twitter/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/extend.js:15:14)
<     at new child (/projects/twitter/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/extend.js:15:14)
<     at Function.collection (/projects/twitter/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/bookshelf.js:110:14)
<     at all (/projects/twitter/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/model.js:703:39)
<     at fetchAll (/projects/twitter/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/model.js:768:27)
```

This is my model then collection

```
var Users_Data_At_Time = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'Users_Data_At_Time',
    Users: function(){
        return this.belongsTo(Users);
    },
    Tweets_At_Time: function(){
        return this.hasMany(Tweets_At_Time);
    }
});

var Users_Data_At_Time_Collection = bookshelf.Collection.extend({
model: Users_Data_At_Time
});
```

I've tried to call both the collection and model using .fetchAll

Here is where I'm trying to use the model

```
new Users_Data_At_Time().fetchAll()
.then(function (users) {
        console.log(users);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

I've seen a couple examples and it appears that this is the correct way of doing it but I'm still getting that error.

Any thoughts or ideas would be a huge help

Comment: What version of knex are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do this in all bookshelf but as a work around I found [this overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952960/how-to-do-raw-query-in-bookshelf-js) that uses raw query from knex in bookshelf to select all.

I'm not sure if this is the only solution if there are others please let me know

Answer (score 0):

What might be your problem is the naming of your file/model. The table name is snake_cased in your database, so that's obviously fine. But the model name needs to be PascalCased (aka UpperCamelCase). The INVERSE goes for your file, so it should be snake_cased.

Check this guy out, specifically the last paragraph:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bookshelf-model